# SQL Server 2017, how to transform specific rows into to column header?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2017

After Importing a flat .csv file I do clean up dirty data and then I am left with this issue where the first column of each "section" needs to be the an ID of that group.

Here is how the table looks in SQL:

```
a           |   b           |   c
-------------------------------------------
alpha 1011  |               |
1           |   10/20/2019  |   10/20/2020
2           |   10/20/2018  |   10/20/2019
3           |   10/20/2017  |   10/20/2018
4           |   10/20/2016  |   10/20/2017
alpha 1012  |               |
5           |   10/20/2015  |   10/20/2016
6           |   10/20/2014  |   10/20/2015
7           |   10/20/2013  |   10/20/2014
8           |   10/20/2012  |   10/20/2013
alpha 1013  |               |
9           |   10/20/2011  |   10/20/2012
10          |   10/20/2010  |   10/20/2011
11          |   10/20/2009  |   10/20/2010
12          |   10/20/2008  |   10/20/2009
```

Here is how to create the temp table:

```
CREATE TABLE #Temp_CSV_Import
(
    a varchar(255),
    b varchar(255),
    c varchar(255)
)

INSERT INTO #Temp_CSV_Import (a, b, c) values ('alpha 1011', '', '')
INSERT INTO #Temp_CSV_Import (a, b, c) values ('1', '10/20/2019', '10/20/2020')
INSERT INTO #Temp_CSV_Import (a, b, c) values ('2', '10/20/2018', '10/20/2019')
INSERT INTO #Temp_CSV_Import (a, b, c) values ('3', '10/20/2017', '10/20/2018')
INSERT INTO #Temp_CSV_Import (a, b, c) values ('4', '10/20/2016', '10/20/2017')
INSERT INTO #Temp_CSV_Import (a, b, c) values ('alpha 1012', '', '')
INSERT INTO #Temp_CSV_Import (a, b, c) values ('5', '10/20/2015', '10/20/2016')
INSERT INTO #Temp_CSV_Import (a, b, c) values ('6', '10/20/2014', '10/20/2015')
INSERT INTO #Temp_CSV_Import (a, b, c) values ('7', '10/20/2013', '10/20/2014')
INSERT INTO #Temp_CSV_Import (a, b, c) values ('8', '10/20/2012', '10/20/2013')
INSERT INTO #Temp_CSV_Import (a, b, c) values ('alpha 1013', '', '')
INSERT INTO #Temp_CSV_Import (a, b, c) values ('9', '10/20/2011', '10/20/2012')
INSERT INTO #Temp_CSV_Import (a, b, c) values ('10', '10/20/2010', '10/20/2011')
INSERT INTO #Temp_CSV_Import (a, b, c) values ('11', '10/20/2009', '10/20/2010')
INSERT INTO #Temp_CSV_Import (a, b, c) values ('12', '10/20/2008', '10/20/2009')

SELECT * FROM #Temp_CSV_Import

DROP TABLE #Temp_CSV_Import
```

Then I want the result to look like this:

```
a  |    b          |    c          |    alpha
-----------------------------------------------
1  |    10/20/2019 |    10/20/2020 |    1011
2  |    10/20/2018 |    10/20/2019 |    1011
3  |    10/20/2017 |    10/20/2018 |    1011
4  |    10/20/2016 |    10/20/2017 |    1011
5  |    10/20/2015 |    10/20/2016 |    1012
6  |    10/20/2014 |    10/20/2015 |    1012
7  |    10/20/2013 |    10/20/2014 |    1012
8  |    10/20/2012 |    10/20/2013 |    1012
9  |    10/20/2011 |    10/20/2012 |    1013
10 |    10/20/2010 |    10/20/2011 |    1013
11 |    10/20/2009 |    10/20/2010 |    1013
12 |    10/20/2008 |    10/20/2009 |    1013
```

Can I get the result table with a SQL script?

Comment: There are significant problems here.  The most important is that rows in SQL don't have a position or any implicit ordering - SQL, by design, treats the data as un-ordered sets.  Although you show that there are 4 rows related to 'alpha 1011' because of where they are in the sequence, that sequence does not exist in SQL.  You ***must*** do some processing on the CSV file ***before*** it is loaded in to your database, to add one more column which explicits states "this is row 1", "this is row 2", etc, etc.  Then, if you're doing that outside of SQL, you may as well do the rest outside of SQL.

Comment: @MatBailie Good point. I think an [identity column](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-table-transact-sql-identity-property?view=sql-server-2017) in the table could solve that.

Comment: @DávidLaczkó - That depends on how you insert the data in to the table, you need to very rigorously check that how you load the data ***can't*** change the order.  `BULK INSERT`, for example, does ***not*** guarantee that the order is retained.

Comment: @MatBailie Another good point, the import method needs to be investigated for that.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks. I added another IDENTITY column 'x' to the temp table then I came up with the following:

```
DECLARE @tempVal varchar(255), @intMin INT, @intMax INT, @tempAlphaVal varchar(15)

-- Assigning the first value in the dataset -- starting the loop
SET @intMin = (SELECT MIN(x) FROM #Temp_CSV_Import)

-- Assigning the last value in the dataset -- stoping the loop
SET @intMax = (SELECT Max(x) FROM #Temp_CSV_Import)

-- adding another column to the table
ALTER TABLE #Temp_CSV_Import ADD alpha varchar(15);

WHILE (@intMin <= @intMax)
BEGIN   
    -- find the value of column a in row @intMin
    SET @tempVal = (SELECT a FROM #Temp_CSV_Import WHERE x = @intMin)   

    -- check to see if the value has alpha  
    IF(@tempVal LIKE '%alpha%') 
        BEGIN           
            -- parse the string to get the number -- until the next alpha use this number
            SET @tempAlphaVal = (SELECT SUBSTRING(@tempVal, CHARINDEX(' ', @tempVal) +1, 20))           
        END
    ELSE
        BEGIN   
            -- update apha with the temp value in @tempAlphaVal     
            UPDATE #Temp_CSV_Import SET alpha = @tempAlphaVal WHERE x = @intMin
        END

    -- increment @intMin
    SET @intMin = @intMin + 1                   
END

-- lastly delete the alpha row since we do not need it anymore.
DELETE FROM #Temp_CSV_Import WHERE alpha is null

SELECT * FROM #Temp_CSV_Import
```